# Знаки препинания в предложении с СПП и БСП связью

Tags: пунктуация, спп, бсп

Какой вариант из двух предложенных является верным?

1. Я долго собирался, чтобы попасть в школу — опоздал.
2. Я долго собирался, чтобы попасть в школу, — опоздал.

Мне кажется, что второй вариант верный.

Comment: Если мне кажется, то могу дать тому объяснение. Можете пояснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, верный второй вариант.
"Опоздал" является следствием. Судя по всему, здесь оформление — БСП, в котором второе подлежащее пропущено, а не простое предложение. Иначе было бы:
*Я долго собирался, чтобы попасть в школу, и — опоздал.*

Розенталь указывал, что при отношениях следствия запятая, закрывающая придаточное предложение, сохраняется:
*Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176